# How can I tell how many kills my soldier is away from promotion?

Tags: xcom-2

How can I tell how many kills my soldier is away from promotion?  I'd like to get this information, especially when in the middle of a battle, as if I know that I'm just a few kills away from a promotion and the enemy is sending reinforcements, I can reliably "farm" for a bit to get that soldier his/her promotion.

Comment: In the base game, you can't, unless you're meticulous about counting kills and mission completions. It gets more complicated than that, though, since kills are worth different amounts of XP, and the XP threshold needed for promotion varies based on difficulty.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*Alright, I dug into the code some more and updated my answer.*

Here are the number of kills needed for each level, taken from `DefaultGameData_XPData.ini`:

```
            Rookie  Veteran  Commander  Legend
Squaddie   |   1  |    1    |    1    |    1
Corporal   |   5  |    6    |    6    |    8
Sergeant   |  12  |   12    |   12    |   18
Lieutenant |  24  |   24    |   24    |   40
Captain    |  38  |   38    |   42    |   70
Major      |  57  |   57    |   60    |  110
Colonel    |  81  |   81    |   85    |  175
```

However, there's more to it than just straight-up kills.

Every time a unit gets a kill, *all* the other units on that mission get partial-kills.  The game calls these "`KillAssists`", but that's a misleading name because the unit earns a `KillAssist` whether or not they did any damage.

How much a "`KillAssist`" is worth varies by class
*(taken from DefaultClassData.ini, variable name `KillAssistsPerKill`)*

```
Specialist:    1/3rd kill
Psi Operative: 1/3rd kill
Rookie:        1/4th kill
Ranger:        1/4th kill
Sharpshooter:  1/5th kill
Grenadier:     1/5th kill
```

Additionally, Psi Operatives gets a kill bonus called a "`PsiCredit`", worth 1/3rd kill, every time they are hit by Feedback.

Finally, if a unit started at any rank above 'Rookie', they'll have additional hidden bonus kills equal to the number necessary for that rank.

---

Assuming you obtained a unit at 'Rookie', you can see how many kills they have in the armory...

[image: Armory kills]

but without a save-file viewer *(which doesn't exist AFAIK)* you cannot view their `KillAssists`.  The best we can do is guesstimate from the number of missions.

In my screenshot above, if we assume she's encountered, say, 8 enemies per mission on average, then over 10 missions she's encountered `10*8=80` enemies.  That gives her `80-29=51` KillAssists, which counts for `51/4=12` kills, bringing her approximate kill-total to `29+12=41` kills.  So she needs around 16 kills or 64 KillAssists to level up to Major.

**Edit: There is now a mod that shows KillAssists on the soldier info screen: [Accurate Soldier XP](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=631392567)**

---

Some other interesting things I discovered while code-diving:

- Except for rookies, units only gain levels after actually getting a kill, so you can't have a Colonel with 0 kills.
- Kills are still kept track of after getting a promotion mid-mission, so people who claim *"When a unit gets a promotion further kills are wasted"* are incorrect.  However, it *is* true that a unit can only gain one level per mission, even if they pass the threshold for two levels.  In that case, they'll get promoted immediately on their first kill in the next mission.
- As of the latest patch, Wet Works (25% XP boost) is no longer retroactive.  `KillAssists` and `PsiCredits` are *not* boosted by Wet Works.
- Despite popular claims to the contrary, there is no XP in this game, it was disabled before the game's release *(`bUseFullXpSystem=false`)*.  Though, I suppose you could consider `KillAssists` and `PsiCredits` a form of XP...
- I've created [a mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=623935276) that gives a small number of kills to idle units *(for technical reasons I can't add `KillAssists`)*.  There's an option to allow them to level up outside of missions as well.

Comment: So this means that the "wet work" research (+25% experience for each kill) is basically useless?

Comment: I'll second that -- how does "Wet Work" factor into this? Reducing the threshold by 25% per tier, I'd imagine?

Comment: I have removed some obsolete comments, since this answer has been completely updated.

Comment: I think the: "Units only gain levels after actually getting a kill, so you can't have a Colonel with 0 kills." part is wrong. On the first mision if you kill all 6 enemies, all your men will be promoted, even if they did not kill anything.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Great update. This all makes a lot more sense now. The fact wetworks only boosts kills and not assists is also very interesting since it makes it a lot weaker than it appears.

Comment: @MTilsted:  Ah you're right, I missed that!  Edited my answer.

Comment: Useful Note: I bought Wet Work the other day, and one of my soldiers was immediately promoted. Didn't need to wait for a fight.

Comment: Are you sure about not being able to level up twice? I know for sure after the Avenger Defense mission I was able to rank up my Grenadier from Corporal to Lieutenant.

Comment: SPARK gets 4 KillAssistsPerKill.